# What is the point of a Stack Trace in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

Sometimes Xcode encounters an error - but rather than throw a proper "end of program" and give me a description, all I get is a "paused" view, much like if I had set a breakpoint. All I see is a huge stack trace, and I can press the "execute program" function several million times, moving the trace forward once line at a time. All it does is frustrate me and wear out my track pad.

I wonder if there is any way to make use of this Stack Trace, or if I can move the trace forward to the "real" problem, or extract a human usable description from it.

Sometimes an exception breakpoint helps to prevent a Stack Trace, but usually I feel the  debugger is letting me down. Or am I missing something and does the Stack Trace actually contain information I can use to show the problem?

Comment: The point is to try and show you what went wrong.  Unfortunately in a multi-threaded environment like iOS it isn't always obvious from the stack trace which thread and therefore which bit of code had the error.  Try setting an "Exception Breakpoint" from the breakpoint inspector.  You should also get a message in the output console window to give you some clues as to what went wrong.   Here is one tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5 and

Comment: Yes, I like he exception breakpoints, they're helpful sometimes. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Paulw11 this comment is, frankly, more useful than the "answers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually it does stop at the "real" problem and pauses the execution to store the current state of of operation. Even as a lowly undergrad I've used it many times.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"This is not what you should do"<<std::endl;
    int sum = 0;
    int target = 6;
    for(int i = target; i>=0;--i){
        sum += 1/i;
    }
    std::cout<<"we never see this but still it should give us a partial sum of the harmanic sequence "<<sum<<std::endl;
}
```

This would output the sum of 1/n from 1 to target but it tries to do it starting at 0. When it crashes the paused state of execution makes it easy to see what's wrong.

If you want you can always quit the program by clicking the stop button in the upper left

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows you where the crash happened (the point where you stopped). This isn't always in your code, so you can look down the stack trace to where your code actually is called, and if you're lucky you can examine the values of arguments to functions and local variables which will hopefully give you enough context to understand why the crash occurred.

I've never been able to continue, so my strategy is to try to understand why we crashed in a more global sense (e.g. looking at what other threads were doing) then fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is trying to tell you where something went wrong. 
It's not easy to read, especially when it breaks on application main. 
There's an art to learning how to use debugging tools and this is one of them. 
One place to start is with the documentation. 
There are some older but mostly still relevant articles on Apple's developer site about reading a stack trace and working with the debugging facilities. 
There are also some great WWDC videos on the topic that are well worth your time.

In general if you're lost, look to when it happens. 
This gives you more clues. 
Clues where to put breakpoints. 
Breakpoints help you isolate a section of code that compiled but doesn't actually work. 
You can then step through your breakpoints until the big bad stack trace comes. That will help usually. 
You can also use "caveman debugging" and start peppering your code with NSLog calls to help isolate in a similar way.

Beyond that you'll want those WWDC videos. 
You'll find a lot of technical tools available that you hopefully don't need often.

The stack trace will start to make more sense but you'll probably never understand all of it unless you do it a lot and work on compilers.

Comment: Unfortunately, they might all be time sensitive. Each version of Xcode has significant changes. It is very reasonable to expect a developer to go the Apple Developer site and find and view Xcode docs and videos.